# Can't upgrade a SQL Express to SQL Standard

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-express, sql-server-2014

I have a 64 bit SQL Server 2008 Express R2 installed and I cannot upgrade it to a fully licensed 2014 Standard. When I try to update to SP 4, I get this issue:

[image]

If I try to run the upgrade edition, notice there is no "Instance Select" option for me to select my instance:

[image]

However, I am able to connect and run to the database, and get the properties:

[image]

So my question is, I'm able to use the existing SQL express instance, but I cannot upgrade the service pack or upgrade the edition. I'm at a loss here. Any thoughts? Below is the summary of the install log:

```
Overall summary:
  Final result:                  Passed
  Exit code (Decimal):           0
  Start time:                    2015-08-11 12:12:19
  End time:                      2015-08-11 12:19:27
  Requested action:              EditionUpgrade

Machine Properties:
  Machine name:                  xxxxxxxx
  Machine processor count:       8
  OS version:                    Windows 8
  OS service pack:               
  OS region:                     United States
  OS language:                   English (United States)
  OS architecture:               x64
  Process architecture:          64 Bit
  OS clustered:                  No

Product features discovered:
  Product              Instance             Instance ID                    Feature                                  Language             Edition              Version         Clustered  Configured
  SQL Server 2008 R2   xxxxDBSERVER         MSSQL10_50.xxxxxBSERVER        Database Engine Services                 1033                 Express Edition      10.50.1600.1    No         Yes       
  SQL Server 2008 R2                                                       Management Tools - Basic                 1033                 Express Edition      10.50.1600.1    No         Yes       

Package properties:
  Description:                   Microsoft SQL Server 2014 
  ProductName:                   SQL Server 2014
  Type:                          RTM
  Version:                       12
  SPLevel:                       0
  Installation location:         E:\x64\setup\
  Installation edition:          Standard

User Input Settings:
  ACTION:                        EditionUpgrade
  CONFIGURATIONFILE:             C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150811_121219\ConfigurationFile.ini
  ENU:                           true
  FEATURES:                      BROWSER
  HELP:                          false
  IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS:  true
  INDICATEPROGRESS:              false
  INSTANCENAME:                  <empty>
  PID:                           *****
  QUIET:                         false
  QUIETSIMPLE:                   false
  UIMODE:                        Normal
  X86:                           false

  Configuration file:            C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150811_121219\ConfigurationFile.ini

Detailed results:
  Feature:                       SQL Browser
  Status:                        Passed

Rules with failures:

Global rules:

There are no scenario-specific rules.

Rules report file:               C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\120\Setup Bootstrap\Log\20150811_121219\SystemConfigurationCheck_Report.htm
```

Answer (score 6):

Your problem is you are trying to install Service Pack 4 for SQL Server 2008 (the original release, not R2) on a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance.

Despite the similar names, SQL Server 2008 and SQL Server 2008 R2 are different releases, with different Service Packs.

Apply the correct Service Pack for SQL Server 2008 R2 (the latest is [SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 3](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44271)), then you should be able to upgrade to 2014 Standard with no problem.